# Showing a linear map is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that if $T$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
>   $$\mathrm{null}(T) = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) ∈ \mathbb{R}^4 : x_1 = 5x_2,\, x_3 = 7x_4\},$$
>   then $T$ is surjective.

I'm not intuitively seeing how this is true. Just because you're given the null space, can't everything else just be mapped to one element and the map wouldn't be surjective?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Stahl's excellent hint will help you solve the problem. But I wanted to address your question:  you can't "map everything else to one element" unless that element is also 0. If some $v\in \mathbb{R}^4$ is mapped to a non-zero element $w\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then $2v$ is mapped to $2w$, which is not equal to $w$.